# Reproducing two-way ANOVA results based on treatment means and standard errors

Tags: anova, descriptive-statistics

I am currently reviewing a paper and would like to reproduce their statistical tests in order to see if what they do is accurate.

The experiment has 2 factors: four soil types and five levels of glucose addition, which results in 20 different treatments. Each treatments is replicated 3 times (total of 60 replicates). They do provide the mean and standard error for soil organic matter respiration (the variable I'm interested in) for each of the 20 treatments.

My question is: can I reproduce the ANOVA results based on this summary data?
So far I'm trying to do it manually: I have already calculated the sum of squares for the first factor (soil type), the sum of squares for the second factor (glucose addition), and the sum of squares within - but I'm not sure whether I can also calculate the Total sum of squares without the original data.

If anyone knows about an R package that can do this, that would of course also be appreciated.